# Optional write-out parameter for c++ function

Tags: c++, templates

I have a function with 'optional' parameter that can be used to collect intermediate output.

For example, let's say I am collecting the partial sums, when summing an array, like this:

```
template<bool writeout> double sumNumbers(const std::vector<double> &numbers, double *out_partialsums) {
    double total = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++) {
        total += numbers[i]; 

        /* ... */

        if (writeout) {
            out_partialsums[i] = total;
        }
    }
    return total;
}
```

(`double *` used for the sake of argument here)

However I want it to be callable with the 'writeout' parameter completely disabled, ie:

1. I want the 'writeout' branch to be removed by the compiler if writeout is set to false, so we don't check it and branch every iteration of the inner loop.
2. I want to avoid duplicating any of the implementation (let's imagine the actual function is much more complicated than this one)
3. I want to be able to use both versions of the function elsewhere in my code (can't do this with a #DEFINE sort of thing).

If I use the above example then I'd still have to provide a 'dummy' pointer at the callsite like:

```
auto result = sumNumbers<false>(numbers, NULL)
```

which is not really acceptable. How to solve this?

Comment: 1. Probably already happens. 3. You can have non-template overloads that call the template with any required dummy parameters.

Comment: How about letting the compiler inline that function, in which case it can be stripped as part of optimization? Besides - with an example this complex you wouldn't even have to "worry" about accidentally preventing vectorization, and for a plain branch, branch prediction will make this negletable at runtime.

Comment: First usage case is supported by std::accumulate. Second is supported by std::partial_sum and result is, IIRC, in the last element.

Answer (score 1):

You can use default parameter values for both the template parameter and the function parameter, like this:

```
template<bool writeout = false>
double sumNumbers(const std::vector<double> &numbers, double *out_partialsums = NULL) {
    ...
}
```

and the call will be either with the sub-sum:

```
auto result = sumNumbers<true>(numbers, subsum);
```

or without it:

```
auto result = sumNumbers(numbers);
```